# How do I uninstall PHP APC 3.1.9 and do a clean install?

Tags: php, osx-lion, apc

### Details:

OS: Mac OS X 10.7.3

PHP 5.3.8: Shipped with Mac OS

How APC was installed: sudo pecl install apc-3.1.9

If I try the same command, it shows the following: pecl/apc is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.9
install failed

I need to re-install APC because the Debugging is enable and PHP its throwing "Notice: Unknown: apc_cache_find" everywhere.

The debugging setting is not included in the configuration:
http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

I can't disable APC because I'm working on a website that use it.

I have been looking for hours but I couldn't find the answer, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `sudo pecl uninstall apc-3.1.9` not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo pecl uninstall apc-3.1.9
```